# SSAS - Empty Generated Time Dimension Table

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssms

I'm facing a strange problem about SSAS.

I created a time dimension by using Dimension Generator Wizard.
I chosen to create a time dimension in my data source.

It works fine, I can browse by cube and filtering on date.

Now, I would like to browse this table to check values, however the time table is empty in SSMS. So when I select the "TOP 100 rows", 0 rows are retrieved.

Comment: What did you select on the "Select Creation Method" page of the Wizard? Data source or server?

Comment: I selected "Data Source" to generate the dimension table in the input source database. In SSMS, I can browse the table it's empty.
If I create the dimension table on the server (other choice), where can I browse the table ? That's so strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a strange mistake, when I browsed the table in SQL Server, no rows were retrieved.
I decided to delete and recreate the Time dimension (created in the data source) by using Dimension Wizard in SSDT. It works well.

To customize the table, I decided to create a view from the dimension table, then I added some changes. Finally, I changed the dimension table to the new view in SSDT (data source view).